How to get rid of React Leaftlet map gray area while scrolling vertically
Hey guys I have use React Leafnet in my web app, everything seems working fine when I scroll map horizontally it loads new map images nicely but when I scroll map vertically, than after some position it shows gray area. This happens on both side(top-down). I tried giving the heigh of 100vh to map container but no success. Please do help me.
For testproject link-
stmap.earth-team.org

